# zend db intersect

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, intersect

Does Zend_Db_Select object support Intersect?. It supports union (i.e this is possible, $db->select->union($sql1,$sql2) ), but when I look at the documentation, there is no method like intersect.

So How else is intersection possible with Zend_Db?

Answer (score 0):

As much as I don't want to say this, but `Zend_Db_Select` does not support anything with `INTERSECT`. You will have to use your ingenuity to make this possible. You can extend `Zend_Db_Select` to add that functionality or build your SQL string and use the Adapter to fetch the records.

It shouldn't be too hard to accomplish the following by extending `Zend_Db_Select`

```
$sql1 = new My_Db_Select($db);
$sql1->from('tbl1');
$sql2 = $db->select();
$sql2->from('tbl2');
$sql1->intersect($sql2); // alternate usage, $sql1->intersect($sql2, $sql3, $sql4);
echo $sql1; // prints SELECT * FROM tbl1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM tbl2
```

In order to accomplish that, you will have to create a storage for your intersect objects when adding objects via `My_Db_Select::intersect` and then create `My_Db_Select::assemble` to first call `$sql = parent::assemble` and then loop through the intersect parts and append each call to `assemble` on each. `foreach($intersect as $select) $sql .= ' INTERSECT ' . $select->assemble();`